# TChart axis scaled by hours of the day

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, teechart

I've been trying for about an hour now fiddling with the `TChart`'s Left Axis to make it show the hour of the day.

For example...

- 8:00 PM
- 6:00 PM
- 4:00 PM
- 2:00 PM
- 12:00 AM
- 10:00 AM
- 8:00 AM

In the back-end, I have a 24-hour day range (0 - 24) for the Minimum / Maximum. I've tried setting the Left Axis Label Value Format to `h:nn AM/PM`, but to no avail. It just displays that exact formatting text instead of any realistic data.

How do I make the `TChart`'s left axis display an hourly range of the time of day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to set series YValues to datetime, for example:

```
  Chart1[0].YValues.DateTime := True;
```

You can also set this at design time here :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this for axis;

```
RoundFirstLabel := False;
ExactDateTime := False;
DateTimeFormat := 'hh:nn AM/PM';
Increment := 1/24;
```

Comment: Thanks. I ultimately changed the methodology of this particular chart I was working on to a different chart type. But this will be helpful in the future for other charts.